# Provide package id for project reference

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have two projects in a solution, ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectA has a ProjectReference to ProjectB.
Both projects are built as nuget packages. The PackageId for ProjectB is lets say PackageB.
The resulting nuspec file of PackageA has a dependency like

```xml
 <dependency id="ProjectB" version="..." />
```

Project names are not equal package ids!

How can I create a PackageA with a reference to "PackageB" instead of "ProjectB"? How can I make MSBuild using the value of <PackageId> instead of the project name?

I had a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#projectreference to find some attribute, but without luck.

I also tried to create ItemGroups with Conditions, so that locally I include the ProjectReference and for the Release I include the PackageReference, but because for Release config there is no build dependence for the projects, they can build in random order which may fail due to missing packages.